# scala sbt options to trust multiple nexus repositories

Tags: linux, scala, proxy, sbt, nexus

We are developing scala applications behind a corporate proxy (that requires authentication) with an Internally managed Nexus repository. We are using the scala sbt to maintain our projects. Many of our application dependencies are hosted outside of the internal Nexus repository, however we have some custom built dependencies also, which are maintained in the Internal Nexus. Some projects make use of a mix of internally and externally hosted dependencies, therefore go through the Proxy for some, and not for others. Our internal Nexus repo only works over HTTPS and requires a root CA to authenticate.

The issue is that when accessing the Internet for dependencies, we need to set the proxy configuration in the sbt options, as per below:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyUser=foo -Dhttp.proxyPassword=bar -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhost.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyUser=foo -Dhttps.proxyPassword=bar"
```

When accessing nexus we need to configure to use a keystore with the root CA to authenticate:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foo -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=\"nexus.foo\""
```

The issue is we need to switch between the 2 configurations many times when building projects, depending on if the sbt is accessing the Internet or Internal Nexus.

Do we need to explicitly add **all** certs into the keystore to trust? As in could we simply add all the external hosts to trust as well as Internal? Or is there a way for the JVM running sbt to authenticate via SSL handshake with a trusted authority for external hosts, but the internal CA for Internal hosts?